# store and fetch bold/italic font from sqlite database

Tags: iphone, sql, ios, database, sqlite

I  tried by make Excel file & import as a csv file in sqlite. But it shows me in normal font rather than bold or italic font.

In my app, I uses the sqlite database and fetches data from it. I want to display some text in italic font,How can i do that??

**Does Sqlite supports Italic?**

Comment: whare you want to display it? in some label , textfiled or some other?

Comment: change font type there where you want to display it

Comment: but from 1000 data there are 500 dates in italic

Comment: this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668774/encoding-problem-in-sqlite-and-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read **bold** text, you are interpreting a "strong" meaning. This strong meaning can be emphasized in a number of different ways (for instance, all caps: BOLD). Your text shouldn't contain information about how the information is *presented* (style), but it **SHOULD** contain information about the meaning (structure). Keeping these two separate gives you more flexibility to change how the text is presented if, say, you wanted to change your website template or application design. You could choose to display strong text as bold, all caps, all caps and underlined, etc. on a whim.

I recommend some subset of HTML, as it is structural by nature and very widely used. In HTML, the bold tag exists (`<b>`; however, it is stylistic, so the `<strong>` tag is recommended to encode the strong meaning instead).

Databases don't support encoding; however, you can encode the text yourself before sticking it in the database. Here is an example of an HTML-encoded string:

```
<p><strong>An HTML-encoded string</strong> inside a paragraph.</p>
```

When you extract it, you could choose to represent the strong text as **bold**:

> **An HTML-encoded string** inside a paragraph.

Or as CAPS:

> AN HTML-ENCODED STRING inside a paragraph.

Or even italic caps:

> *AN HTML-ENCODED STRING* inside a paragraph.

There are many other ways to encode structure, including Mark Down (I believe that's what StackOverflow uses).

Answer (score 1):

yOu should store data with rules, as in case html we store it as `<b>topic/b><i>this is topic</i>` i mean by adding proper tagging before save.
I am not share about `ios` or `xcode` how but you should add some extra information to text before saving the text.

Answer (score -1):

where you want to display it? in some label , textfiled or some other? change font type there where you want to display it

For example if you want to display it in UILable

then change the font type of UILabel

```
    [<lblname> setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:<whatever_you_want>]];
```

**It's your bad logic to fetch bold text from database.**

Enjoy Programming

Comment: ya,but the fonts are dynamically changes as per question. and in a string the limited words are italics.

Comment: then you have to apply condition for that dynamic text depending upon your requirements. There's no way to fetch bold text from db

Comment: as a e.g. if there is a question which contain a 4-5 words in italic & and same as answers for that question. others are in normal font.